# Dynamic Vue Import from a subfolder

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to import all `.vue` files in a certain subfolder into another component. I know about [Global registration of Base components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Automatic-Global-Registration-of-Base-Components) but this does not seem to help me here.

Let's say I have default Vue component (not the main one) with something like this:

```js
export default {
  components: {
    red: () => import('./panes/red'),
  },
  data() {
    return {
      current: false,
    };
  },
```

and my file structure is something like:

```
/src
- main.js
- main.vue
-- components/
-- panes/
--- /red.vue
--- /green.vue
--- /blue.vue
-- SubMain.vue
```

I am trying to dynamically create the `components` object for the `SubMain.vue` folder.

So I try something like this in `SubMain.vue`:

```
  import myComponents from './src/components/panes';

  ...

  components: Object.keys(myComponents).reduce((obj, name) => {
    return Object.assign(obj, { [name]: () => import(myComponents[name]) })
  }, {}),
```

But eslint is giving me errors about `Missing file extension` and `Unable to resolve path to module` on the `myComponents` variable. Yes, I double checked my path and tried other paths. Nothing. I am using the Vue CLI 3 project.

Comment: where's the `panes` folder?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Added it in. It's all in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Webpack, you can use `require.context`:

```js
import _kebabCase from lodash/kebabCase

const components = require.context('src/panes', true)

components.keys().map(component => {
    // turn './ComponentName.vue' into 'component-name'
    const componentName = _kebabCase(
        component.replace(/^\.\//, '').replace(/\.vue$/, '')
    )
    // register new component globally
    Vue.component(componentName, components(component))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can import multiple components that way without an index file that aggregates the component import/exports for you. See [Import multiple components in vue using ES6 syntax doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43060814/import-multiple-components-in-vue-using-es6-syntax-doesnt-work)